# st cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, android

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    TextView textView1;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    String st1 = "ask1";
    String st2 = "ask2";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            { 
                for(int i=1; i<5; i++) 
                { 
                    switch (v.getId())  
                    { 
                    case R.id.button1: textView1.setText(String.valueOf(st[i]));
                        i++;
                        break; 
                    } 
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Ругается на "st"...
st cannot be resolved to a variable.   В чем проблема?

Comment: где объявление st?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас объявлены `st1` и `st2`, а вы обращаетесь к массиву `st`, который в коде у вас не объявлен.